# Overwrite method inside an objective-c class as in Java

Tags: java, objective-c

I often use this statement for extending class without needs of writing a whole separate file. Supposing ClassFromFramework is a class being part of a framework included in library.

```
public ClassFromFramework {

   public String myMethod() {
      // operations
   }

   //lot of other methods....

}
```

Then in my class I could do the following:

```
import com.framework.ClassFromFramework;

public MyClass {

   public void method() {

      ClassFromFramework m = new ClassFromFramework() {
        @Override
        public String myMethod() {
          // do operations...
        }
      } 

      m.myMethod();
   }
}
```

I wonder if I can achieve the same with Objective-c without declaring a new combination .h .m files and import in my using class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make a new subclass, and override methods, but all new classes must be in their own .h & .m files. That's how Obj-C operates. In this case, it would make sense to have the additional files.

You can also call the parent method with the word super. This is done all the time when subclassing a ViewController, such as in viewDidLoad.

Comment: Well, you were right. Considering the above example, the only 'workaround' I found is to declare both the .h and .m with .h extending ClassFromFramework, directly in the MyClass.m implementation. I hope I made myself clear :-)