# Objective-C equivalent for Java anonymous inner class

Tags: ios, objective-c

How can i override a single method for a single instance in Objective-C ?

In Java i do something like this:

```java
public static void main(String[] args){
   MyClass aObject = new MyClass(){
     @Override
     public int myMethod(Object someParameter){
        // Some custom code
        ...
        // Call the super method
        return super.myMethod(someParameter);
     }
   };
}
```

I need to do this because i must receive a notification through `NSNotificationCenter` if a specific WebPage is going to be loaded (`webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType:`).

The UIWebView, i want to observe, is nested in a `CDVViewController` (Custom class from [apache cordova](http://cordova.apache.org)) netherless I can't just override the delegate of the view controllers's web view, because the original delegate has instantiation code which enables PhoneGap to run.

Comment: You may want to have a look at this question I asked, it is basically the same: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13089932/overwrite-method-inside-an-objective-c-class-as-in-java